# Laravel - Different $URL after verification Email

Tags: redirect, laravel-8, email-verification

In my app, there are two types of users. A group of them, as admins, must register themselves, and the other can only be present after being invited by the admins. Both types of users get verification email. I want the page that these two types of users see, after click on button in verification email, is different. How can I do this?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If You are using laravel/ui for authentication you need to provide path where the user is to be taken based on type in your VerificationController which ensure where to redirect your user after it is verified.

you need to remove  protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME; and replace with below function

```php
public function redirectTo()
 {
   if(auth()->user()->type == 'admin'){
      return '/here';
   }else{
     retuurn 'there'
   }
 }
```

if you are using anything other than laravel/ui you can follow the same procedure and have to redirect manually to certain url